# How do I centre the Y axis in a D3 Tornado Chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm a complete newbie to d3.js but so far I'm quite impressed..

I've been asked to create a Tornado chart and so far I've got pretty much everything working as required, however the client would like the negative X access to be equal on both sides of the Y axis and right now it is simply working off the highest data value.

How do I ensure both sides of the Y access are the same length?

Here is my working code, if you load this you can see the second chart is very one sided.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.bar--positive {
  fill: #9BCCF5;
}

.bar--negative {
  fill: pink;
}

text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
</style>
<body>
<p id="example"></p>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

function tornadoChart() {
  var margin = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 40, left: 100},
    width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var x = d3.scale.linear()
      .range([0, width]);

  var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .rangeRoundBands([0, height], 0.1);

  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient("bottom")
      .ticks(10)


  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient("left")
      .tickSize(0)

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


  function chart(selection) {
    selection.each(function(data) {

      x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.interactions; })).nice();
      y.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.age; }));

      var minInteractions = Math.max.apply(Math, data.map(function(o){return o.interactions;}))*-1;
      yAxis.tickPadding(Math.abs(x(minInteractions) - x(0)) + 10);

      var bar = svg.selectAll(".bar")
          .data(data)

      bar.enter().append("rect")
          .attr("class", function(d) { return "bar bar--" + (d.interactions < 0 ? "negative" : "positive"); })
          .attr("x", function(d) { return x(Math.min(0, d.interactions)); })
          .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.age); })
          .attr("width", function(d) { return Math.abs(x(d.interactions) - x(0)); })
          .attr("id", function(d){ return d.age})
          .attr("style", function(d){ return d.colour == null ? "" : "fill:" + d.colour;})
          .attr("height", y.rangeBand())

      bar.enter().append('text')
          .attr("text-anchor", "end")
          .attr("x", function(d,i) {

              var titlePlacement = Math.abs(x(d.interactions) - x(0)) + x(Math.min(0, d.interactions))-5;
              if( Math.abs(x(d.interactions) - x(0)) < 30 && d.interactions > 0)
               titlePlacement += 30;
              else if(d.interactions < 0) //Negative placement
              {
                titlePlacement = x(Math.min(0, d.interactions))-5;

              }


              return titlePlacement;
          })
          .attr("y", function(d,i) {
              return y(d.age) + (y.rangeBand() / 2);
          })
          .attr("dy", ".35em")
          .text(function (d) { return d.interactions; })

      svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "x axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(xAxis);
      svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "y axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(0) + ",0)")
          .call(yAxis);

    });

  }

  return chart;
}



var data = {"MyData":[{"age":"18-24","gender":"male","interactions":21600,"colour":"#ecf"},{"age":"18-24","gender":"female","interactions":-15500,"colour":""},{"age":"25-34","gender":"male","interactions":19500,"colour":"#ecf"},{"age":"25-34","gender":"female","interactions":-5000,"colour":"#ecf"},{"age":"35-44","gender":"male","interactions":10700,"colour":""},{"age":"35-44","gender":"female","interactions":-3500,"colour":"#4264FF"},{"age":"45-54","gender":"male","interactions":5700,"colour":"#ecf"},{"age":"45-54","gender":"female","interactions":-2400,"colour":"#ecf"},{"age":"55-64","gender":"male","interactions":2500,"colour":"#ecf"},{"age":"55-64","gender":"female","interactions":-1100,"colour":"#4264FF"},{"age":"65+","gender":"male","interactions":600,"colour":"#4264FF"},{"age":"65+","gender":"female","interactions":-600,"colour":"#ecf"}],"Other":[{"age":"18-24","gender":"male","interactions":21600},{"age":"18-24","gender":"female","interactions":-5500},{"age":"25-34","gender":"male","interactions":19500},{"age":"25-34","gender":"female","interactions":-5000},{"age":"35-44","gender":"male","interactions":10700},{"age":"35-44","gender":"female","interactions":-3500},{"age":"45-54","gender":"male","interactions":5700},{"age":"45-54","gender":"female","interactions":-2400},{"age":"55-64","gender":"male","interactions":2500},{"age":"55-64","gender":"female","interactions":-1100},{"age":"65+","gender":"male","interactions":600},{"age":"65+","gender":"female","interactions":-600}]};

for (var i in data) {
  var chart = tornadoChart()
  d3.select("#example")
      .datum(data[i])
      .call(chart);
}

</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways for positioning the y axis in the centre, this is one of them:

Find the maximum absolute value in your x scale...

```
var maxvalue = (Math.abs(d3.min(data, function(d) {
        return d.interactions; 
    })) > Math.abs(d3.max(data, function(d) { 
        return d.interactions; 
    }))) ? Math.abs(d3.min(data, function(d) {
        return d.interactions; 
    })) : Math.abs(d3.max(data, function(d) {
        return d.interactions; 
    }));
```

And use this value to set a symmetrical domain:

```
x.domain([maxvalue*-1, maxvalue]);
```

This is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b1xhyo6c/1/